# Combining two 'and's in Criteria Mongo Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I want to create a function that checks for sender and recipient but I need to also get the recipient and sender. Sender and Recipient OR Recipient and Sender.

This is what I want to do but can't. I can't just load the messages sent by sender also need to load them sent by recipient.

```
public List<WebSocketChatMessage> findChatMessages (@RequestParam String sender,
                                                    @RequestParam String recipient) {
    Query query = new Query();
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("sender").is(sender),Criteria.where("recipient").is(recipient));
    Criteria criteria1 = new Criteria();
    criteria1.andOperator(Criteria.where("sender").is(recipient),Criteria.where("recipient").is(sender));
    query.addCriteria(criteria);
    query.addCriteria(criteria1);

    List<WebSocketChatMessage> msgs = mongoTemplate.find(query, WebSocketChatMessage.class);


    return msgs;
}


Document(collection = "chatMsg")
public class WebSocketChatMessage{
private String type;
private String content;
private String sender;
private String chatId;
private String recipient;

public String getRecipient() {
    return recipient;
}

public void setRecipient(String recipient) {
    this.recipient = recipient;
}

public String getChatId() {
    return chatId;
}

public void setChatId(String chatId) {
    this.chatId = chatId;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public void setSender(String sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping("/messages")
public List<WebSocketChatMessage> findChatMessages (@RequestParam String sender,
                                                    @RequestParam String recipient) {
    Query query = new Query();
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where("sender").is(sender).and("recipient").is(recipient), Criteria.where("recipient").is(sender).and("sender").is(recipient));
    query.addCriteria(criteria);

    List<WebSocketChatMessage> msgs = mongoTemplate.find(query, WebSocketChatMessage.class);


    return msgs;
}
```

This seems to work.